# The product of two divergent series is divergent?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This is an TRUE/FALSE queston:

The product of two divergent series is divergent.

The correct answer is FALSE.

I know that the product of two convergent series may not be convergent (i.e. $\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$) according to Cauchy Product.

My question is why "The product of two divergent series may not be divergent"?? Is there any counter example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Take the series $(-1,-2,-2,-2,\dots)$ and the series $(-1,2,-2,2,-2,\dots)$. The Cauchy product of these two series is $(1,0,0,0,\dots)$.

You can think of these as the power series for the  the function $$f(z)=\frac{z+1}{z-1} = 1-2\sum_i z^i$$ and $$g(z)=\frac{z-1}{z+1}=1-2\sum_{i} (-1)^iz^i=f(-z)$$ Neither power series converges at $z=1$, which is the statement that $\sum a_i$ and $\sum b_i$ diverges, but their Cauchy product gives the identity power series...

Essentially, the underlying operation of Cauchy products is the product of the corresponding power series. (This is the "obvious" reason why the Cauchy product of sequences is associative, for example...)

You can define $a_k=k^k$, (with $a_0=1$) and the (Cauchy) multiplicative inverse can be found and the power series likewise will have radius of convergence $0$, and thus $b_i\to\infty$ too.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I am still confused. According to [Cauchy Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) which says 'at least one series is absolute convergent then the product is convergent'. So why the product of two divergent series may convergent? I mean does it disobey the theorem?

Comment: @52145208: That article only states a 1-directional implication (and you've left off half the statement). You can't say that if the product converges, then both factors have to converge; that would be an application of the theorem's converse, but the theorem's converse isn't true.

Comment: @user2357112 Okay. But is there any "elementary" example of this question? I cannot quite follow this answer.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "I cannot quite follow this answer." You can try it with $(a_i)=(1,2,2,2,2,2,\dots)$ and $(b_i)=(1,-2,2,-2,2\dots)$ and prove directly that the Cauchy product is $(1,0,0,0,\dots)$

Comment: You know, this is a homework from Calculus-1 course. Your answer is great! But I don't study so far. I tried to compute $a_i\cdot b_i$, but the result (3 terms each) is $1-2+2+2-4+4+2-4+4$ why it is $(1,0,0,0)$? Thanks!

Comment: That's not the Cauchy production of the series.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you mean pointwise product, this is the simplest counterexample I could think of: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{n} \right) \!\!\! \left( \frac{1}{n} \right) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

but $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ diverges.

Comment: For a simpler counterexample, take the harmonic series on even / odd integers separately, and $0$ everywhere else. The pointwise product is zero.

Comment: @JoeyBF I did not mean this example. This is not Cauchy Product. Actually this is divergent if calculating by Cauchy Product.

Comment: @user61527 Can you give me more details? I cannot understand it. Thanks!

Comment: $a_n=b_n=\frac{1}{n},\ c_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{n-k+1}} = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{(k+1)(n-k+1)}},\ \text{Since}\ k+1\le n+1,\ n-k+1\le n+1, \Rightarrow \sqrt{(k+1)(n-k+1)}\le n+1\Rightarrow c_n\ge\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{n+1}=1$, so it is divergent.

Comment: @52145208 As I wrote, I was assuming pointwise product. I will still leave my answer because it may be useful to others.

Comment: @JoeyBF That sounds great! What do you think about Cauchy product? I mean if it is not pairwise product, do you think the statement is correct? Actually the question does not say which product. Thanks!

Comment: @user61527 Where did the square roots come from? There shouldn't be any square roots in the Cauchy product.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Hi, I am very sad! This is the first college course in China, Calculus-1 (which we call it Advanced Mathematics-1). Lots of deep methods does not appear in this course. But this question seems too difficult to understand (I cannot understand your answer though I bet that must be correct).

Comment: Additionally, I cannot find it even in Wikipedia or any other places. Can you suggest me some reference? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @52145208 The Cauchy product appears when discussing formal power series mostly, which is a more advanced subject. Pointwise product is much simpler conceptually: for two series $\sum_n a_n$ and $\sum_n b_n$, their pointwise product is $\sum_n a_n b_n$. For this product, my answer is a valid counterexample. I cannot find information about this either, but the definition should be simple enough for you to grasp quickly.

Comment: @JoeyBF I guess it also means pairwise product since the Cauchy Product seems too difficult in Calculus-1 course. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sorry? I think you mean to ping 52145208.